# Inconsistent Jackson "Unrecognized field" due to capitalization

Tags: java, jackson

Jackson seems to have a problem when the second letter of a field name is capitalized.

Take a map of values:

```
aaBoolean, true   // works
aBoolean, false   // fails
anInt, 0          // works
aString, "a"      // fails
```

I used Jackson's `ObjectMapper.convertValue(map)` to create a Java object. Here's a snippet of Java code:

```
private boolean aaBoolean;  // GOOD
public boolean getAaBoolean() { return aaBoolean; }
public void setAaBoolean(boolean value) { this.aaBoolean=value;}

private boolean aBoolean;  // FAILS!!! Jackson "Unrecognized field"
public boolean getABoolean() { return aBoolean; }
public void setABoolean(boolean value) { this.aBoolean=value;}
```

I get an error message with all 18 fields. Note the camel case fails when the capital is the second letter:

```
Unrecognized field "aBoolean" (class Test), not marked as ignorable 
(18 known properties: "anInt", "anullableBoolean", "aboolean", "aaBoolean", 
"lastModifiedDate", "adate", "anullableDate", "astring", "anullableString", 
"createdDate", "anullableFloat", "id", "along", "anullableLong", "createdBy", 
"anullableInt", "lastModifiedBy", "afloat"])
```

If I change `aBoolean` to `aaBoolean`, that passes and Jackson fails on `aString`.

Per other Stack Overflow posts, I've verified that the field name and getter/setter match (`aBoolean` is `getABoolean()` and `aaBoolean` is `getAaBoolean()`).

If it matters, here's how the `ObjectMapper` was created:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST"));
```

I can post the full code but I think the above is enough.

I can modify my variable names to get around this, but now I'm curious -  is this a bug or am I missing something about how Jackson handles name conversion?

Comment: My initial guess is that there's something in the JavaBean naming conventions that will treat a single lower case letter as a type indicator (e.g. bValue for a boolean, maybe aValue for an array). But I'm looking for something official in a spec or source code to indicate as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the default Jackson behavior through v2.9 is to lowercase any leading upper case getter/setter methods. So "getURLtoServer" becomes "urltoServer".

Jackson source code executing this here:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.9/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/BeanUtil.java#L246

However, the JavaBean spec says to not change any casing if the first two characters are uppercase. So the JavaBean of "getURLtoServer" would be "URLtoServer".

Jackson introduced MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING as an option to enforce this part of the JavaBean spec. However, it looks like that's being removed in v3.x when it becomes the default behavior:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1772

So for your case, it looks like you can either have the JSON string "aboolean" without using USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING, or else you can have the JSON string "ABoolean" with using USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING.

The other option is to manually specify what you want:

```
@JsonProperty("aBoolean")
public boolean getABoolean() { return aBoolean; }
```

Comment: Without the option set i get aboolean, which is wrong. With it set i get ABoolean, which is wrong differently. Guess there's no auto-way to get aBoolean. The third option, JsonProperty, works so that's what i'll use. Great answer, thanks for helping me understand what's happening.